# Difference between Bitbucket commit history and git logs

Tags: git, bitbucket-cloud

We are using bitbucket cloud for source control. I am trying to analyze merge requests through git commit logs with quite a lot of repos, hence bitbucket UI does not help. We have 4 long term branches (dev, staging, preprod, master) with lots of short term feature branches. I am using git version 2.37.1.windows.1 on my development  machine. Script that I am using has app password Permissions Read for Repositories, Pull Requests on bitbucket. I pulled the updates Today.

I cloned an example repo using git. I used both python pydriller and git log to get csv of commits which create identical results. The command I used on git

```
git log  --pretty=format:%h,%ae,%ai,%s --since=4.weeks >E:\temp\gitoutput.txt
```

When I compared these logs with bitbucket, there are small number of additional commits on bitbucket that are missing from the local git logs. Missing logs do not seem to have a special pattern (specific dates, persons, types) except one type, commit to the master branch which I am interested in.

Regarding missing logs, I looked at the last 100 log entries or so. The last commit was made on 29th of August and the ones missing are:

1. d07fd6d,2 days ago,Person2,Normal Commit
2. fd43ab8,4 days ago,Person1,Normal Commit
3. 7791975,5 days ago,Person1,Normal Commit
4. 3c92bd4,5 days ago,Person1,Merge with Message "Merge branch 'preprod' into master"

I can see all merge requests for other branches, other commits made by Person1 and Person2 but none of Merge into master.

Is there a specific configuration, permissions I need to get all the information? What am I missing?

Comment: I wonder how commit vs author date might be coming into the picture.

Comment: In those commits that you see as being missing in one of the lists, can you elaborate on what their commit/author dates are?

Comment: You are filtering by date. It is possible that those missing merges have a wrong date, such as 1970-01-01.

Comment: @ eftshift0, When I look at the raw commit in bitbucket I see the commit date in From field. However there is no Author dates available in this output. (I know this can be seen from local git but no way in bitbucket UI as far as I can tell)

Comment: @rodrigo I am comparing commits with hash values, so there is no ambiguity on how to locate the commit